# Comparing Byte Arrays In C# (without for loop)

Tags: c#

What is the best way to compare two byte arrays in C#? I do not wish to use a for loop.

I have the following arrays:

```
byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pass);
```

and:

```
byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
```

I have tried using:

```
bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(hashBytes, hash);
```

However, it always returns false.

Comment: Are you sure they are indeed equal in the case where `SequenceEqual` didn't work?

Comment: " I do not wish to use a for loop." - Why not?

Comment: I'd recommend a [constant time comparison](https://github.com/CodesInChaos/Chaos.NaCl/blob/2c861348dc45369508e718aa08611c53b53553db/Chaos.NaCl/CryptoBytes.cs#L51), but of course it still uses a loop.